# Error using parallel_function (matlabpool & parfor)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I want to read a large amount of files, process each of them and save the results for each of them in a `.mat` file. The processing of each file is independent from the others, so I'd like to try using `parfor`. I have written the following Matlab script file:

```
load filelist
obj = package.name.SomeObject();
matlabpool local 5
parfor i=1:length(filelist)
    result = obj.compute(filelist{i});
    [~, name, ~] = fileparts(filelist{i});
    save(['~/path/' name], 'result');
end % file loop
matlabpool close
```

When I try to run it on my computer, a Matlab pool is intialized (`connected to 5 workers`), but then the following error message occurs:

```
Error using parallel_function (line 589)
Undefined function or variable "cleaner".

Error in readfiles (line 14)
parfor i=1:length(filelist)

Error in run (line 64)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why (there might be a connection to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944433/vector-values-differ-if-accessed-outside-or-from-within-parfor)), but the problem was solved by enclosing the code inside a function and calling that function (instead of calling the script file by `run script.m`). It also required creating a `parsave` function (see explanation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-D8103H/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-D8103H&nocookie=true)).