# Vector values differ if accessed outside or from within parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have created this test Matlab script file:

```
numbers = [29 37 44 54 62];

for i=1:length(numbers)
    fprintf('%d\n', numbers(i));
end

fprintf('***\n');

matlabpool local 5;
parfor i=1:length(numbers)
    fprintf('%d\n', numbers(i));
end % image loop
fprintf('***\n')
for i=1:length(numbers)
    fprintf('%d\n', numbers(i));
end
matlabpool close;

fprintf('***\n');

for i=1:length(numbers)
    fprintf('%d\n', numbers(i));
end
```

When I run it, I get consistently the following output:

```
29
37
44
54
62
***
112
111
107
117
115
***
29
37
44
54
62
***
29
37
44
54
62
```

The `fprintf` within the `parfor` block prints the seemingly random set of numbers which is, however, always the same (112, 111, 107, 117, 115). Any idea as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

Interestingly enough, this only happens if I run the script from command line:

```
matlabR2012b -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "run parfortest.m; exit"
```

If I first open a Matlab session and run `parfortest` there, then the numbers are printed correctly.

Comment: Interesting - this doesn't happen to me.  What version are you on?

Comment: What's the `matlab pool` for?  I don't seem to have a license for it, but after I remove that I get the same numbers (although in backwards order).

Comment: `matlabpool` opens a pool of workers to execute parallel code, without it, `parfor` is a simple `for`.

Comment: this doesn't happen on my system neither. I get numbers in random order  (which is expected) but the numbers themselves are correct.

Comment: I've updated the question - it happens only when I run the script file from command line.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on and I think it's a bug.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reproducing it. Let's see if someone else has encountered this before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specifically a problem with run and not a nodesktop issue.  To verify this, you can try

```
>> run parfortest.m
```

from the MATLAB desktop and you'll find the same output.

Although it's not a solution as such; if you omit run, and just use

```
>> parfortest
```

the bad output will be corrected.

Comment: Interesting. That might explain how the path is getting passed to `fprintf` or how `fprint ` is getting confused.

Comment: Agree, calling from cmd window `run parfortest` produces the problem and without the `run` it does not. Therefore, it's not due to command line execution.

Comment: Strangely, if I call `evalin('caller', [script ';'])` from the command window as in `run` I'm unable to replicate the issue - even if I'm in the same directory as the M-file. What else is happening? Shouldn't `'caller'` from the command window be equivalent to that from `run`? Changing the workspace to `'base'` makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate it too on OS X, R2012b. In `mex`, `mexPrintf` is not [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12437). I wouldn't be surprised if Matlab's `fprintf` relies on `mexPrintf` - or similar code - under the hood. If you turn your script into a function - just put `function parfortest` on the first line - the problem goes away, so it may also be a scoping issue.

**EDIT**: Try printing more than five numbers, say twelve of them. Now use `char` to convert these values to ASCII characters. It looks like, in the `parfor` loop `fprintf` is printing out the path to the file you ran via the Terminal command (some form of `parfortest.m` in a randomish order -  I ran the file from `~/Desktop/parfortest.m` and converting the number from `fprintf` to chars I got `D/~ksepotap/frroetst.m`). If you try to print more values than the length of the path then you'll get an error. I can't find a workaround other than turn your script into a function (which is a good idea anyways). Definitely seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't really parallel write a file. Or in this case the output screen since fprintf("text") implies fprintf(1,"text") where 1 is the fileID for the output screen.

The file is now being modified by multiple processes which is a problem because the used buffer is not being flushed before other operations start and the behaviour will be erratical.

Maybe [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/04/19/high-performance-file-io/) link will help.